# How to update an Heroku App created using GitHub "Deploy to Heroku" button?

Tags: git, heroku, github, heroku-toolbelt

I've created an app using a GitHub 'Deploy to Heroku' button. Since the git project has changed, how to update my existing instance with new upstream commits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went and grabbed the original repo and then force pushed it onto my app in Heroku.  Looks like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/USER/REPO.git
git checkout v0.7.3
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/APP-NAME.git
git push -f heroku master
```

Heroku makes it easy to clone the repo for you app using

```
heroku git:clone -a app-name
```

I originally tried doing that and then adding the original repo as a remote and merging changes, but I ran into some trouble which I didn't feel like figuring out.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku's web console can also do this easily. Connect your app to the GitHub repo to deploy automatically or manually from the selected git branch. Automatic deploys can also wait till CI passes. Use the following steps to configure your project.

**Setup**

1. Go to the following section `Deploy` in your app's configuration page
2. For `Deployment method`, click `GitHub`
3. For `App connected to GitHub`, select and connect your repo

**Automatic deploys**

1. Go to the following section `Deploy` > `Automatic deploys` in your app's configuration page
2. Verify/select your desired branch
3. Optionally click `Wait for CI to pass before deploy`
4. Click `Enable Automatic Deploys`

**Manual deploys**

1. Go to the following section `Deploy` > `Manual deploys` in your app's configuration page
2. Verify/select your desired branch
3. Click `Deploy Branch`

**Screenshot**

Here's a screenshot to show the UI:

[image]

> Note: as mentioned by [Tim Malone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1982136/tim-malone), this only works with your own repos, but this can be addressed by creating a fork as mentioned by [Skyost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3608831/skyost).

Comment: The only problem with this is if you have deployed someone else’s app - which is often what the Deploy to Heroku button is used for.

Comment: @TimMalone You only have to create a fork of the repository you want to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it if you already have the app cloned or if you want to clone from Heroku first.

```
# Clone app if you haven't already
heroku git:clone -a appname
# Get latest app
git remote add REPO https://github.com/USER/REPO.git
git branch -b REPO REPO/master
# Delete master
git branch -D master
# Remake it with latest
git checkout -b master
# And force push it to heroku
git push -f heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your local branch is called `master` you could try:

```
git pull heroku master
```

Keep in mind that you may have merge conflicts if your local branch and the remote have diverged.  This also assumes that you have configured `heroku` to point to the appropriate place in the repo.